# URL Rewriting including title

Tags: php, .htaccess

Initially i succeed to rewrite the url using id

**with the htaccess code**:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$1
```

**and link code**

```
a href="link/id.html">
```

It displays successfully :

Then i tried to make url like this:
mysite.com/link/Trekking in Nepal/6.html
where "Trekking in Nepal" is a title in database

I wrote **htaccess code**:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$1
```

**and link code**:

```
a href="link/title/id.html">
```

I cannot successfully rewrite my url to the desired format and get the message 
The requested url is not found on the server

Also when i searched in other sites, i didn't see space, the title is written like "Trekking-in-Nepal".

I am wondering, need help

Thanks

Comment: Url is always starting with '/' not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your rewrite code is not correct:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$1
```

Your link_id is $2, your title is $1. So you should use:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$2
```

Then you should use a slug function for your title, so it's more url friendly. I use something like this:

```
function slug($string, $spaceRepl = "-") {
  // Replace "&" char with "and"
  $string = str_replace("&", "and", $string);

  // Delete any chars but letters, numbers, spaces and _, -
  $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/", "", $string);

  // Optional: Make the string lowercase
  $string = strtolower($string);

  // Optional: Delete double spaces
  $string = preg_replace("/[ ]+/", " ", $string);

  // Replace spaces with replacement
  $string = str_replace(" ", $spaceRepl, $string);

  return $string;
}
```

`slug("Trekking in Nepal")` will be `trekking-in-nepal`, so your link will be:

```
/link/trekking-in-nepal/6.html
```

It should work then with your rewrite code.

Also, I like to rewrite my links like this:

```
/link/trekking-in-nepal-6.html
```

For this I use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$2
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Adi,
I implemented the code as you said, and it works perfectly.  
Cheers :)

Comment: @AdiUlici Hi Adi, I'm new in URL rewriting and I'm trying to understand your answer. You use the function in the .php page where the link (like: www.website.com/link/trekking-in-nepal) will be display and then, when you click on it, the server interprets the rewrited link to hit the "real" page www.website.com/link/post.php?name=trekking_in_nepal on the base of the rule you wrote in .htacces; is this reasoning right?

Comment: @brigo Hello, yes, your reasoning is right. It's just like creating an alias for `/link/post.php?name=[name]` to `/link/[name]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_- ]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ sub_index.php?link_id=$2
```

However you should use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) when you output the title, in order for it to work properly on any kind of browser.

Comment: yeah i did a nonsense mistake....putting link_id=$1 instead of $2
[a-zA-Z0-9_- ]...i think we cannot add a space here
i'll study more about rawurlencode and implement in future projects
thx a lot ))

Comment: @Frozenfire: You could use it, I already gave you the rewrite rule for that, the one I suggested will work for for strings with spaces as well. However, it is recommended not to use spaces.

Comment: really? but when i use your code the page didn't open. There is a error "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." But after i replace [a-zA-Z0-9_- ] with [a-zA-Z0-9_-], it works......so wondering it work for space or not.....maybe there is some server issue.

Comment: @Frozenfire: If the second version works, then do it like that. However, if that doesn't work either, then you have to show us what is already on the `.htaccess` file so we can advice where you should place this line.

Comment: yeah the second version is now working.....just wondering why the space is not accepting.....i make title words seperated by '-' and it is working now.......anyway thx shef