# Change URL usiing htaccess pretty url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to change this URL

> www.sitename.com/page.php?type=template_3&cat=Temples

to be

> www.sitename.com/chennai-Temples/

I tried and referred many sites but I did not get the correct solution to change below URL format and how do I put and read (type and cat) the value in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewriting including title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940644/url-rewriting-including-title)

Comment: I hope this link useful for you..https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the url is not dynamic and you want to change for this url only,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^chennai-Temples/$ page.php?type=template_3&cat=Temples [L]
```