# How do i use .htaccess to clean a url generated by php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hyperlink

I have following URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/item?title=titlename&id=5 and 
http://www.example.com/page?title=titlename
```

I want to convert them like:

```
http://www.example.com/item/titlename/5
http://www.example.com/page/titlename
```

Note: the page and item are files (ie: item.php and page.php), I was able to remove the .php extension using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already "cleaned" the URL that you publish in your application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940644/url-rewriting-including-title and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: No, i haven't cleaned it, i need help to do so, any assistance please?

Comment: Well, "fixing" the URL that you display to your users (in your application) is the very first thing you must do. You don't do this in `.htaccess`. You then use `.htaccess` to _internally rewrite_ the "clean" URL back into the "real" URL that your application understands.

Comment: The application is working just fine, i just want to internally rewrite the url from something like http://www.example.com/item?title=titlename&id=5 and 
http://www.example.com/page?title=titlename to something like this : http://www.example.com/item/titlename/5
http://www.example.com/page/titlename

Answer (score 0):

> i just want to internally rewrite the url from something like `http://www.example.com/item?title=titlename&id=5` and `http://www.example.com/page?title=titlename` to something like this: `http://www.example.com/item/titlename/5` or `http://www.example.com/page/titlename`.

That should be the other way round... *internally rewrite* from `http://www.example.com/item/titlename/5` to `http://www.example.com/item?title=titlename&id=5`. And presumably you should be including the `.php` extension on the target URL? (Don't rely on another directive to do append the file extension.)

Try something like the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\w-]+)(?:/(\d+))?$ /$1.php?title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This will handle a URL both with and without the trailing ID (eg. `/5`). However, if you specify a URL of the form `/item/titlename` (ie. no numeric id), then you will naturally get an empty `id` URL parameter passed to your script.

Note that `MultiViews` must be disabled for this to work, otherwise mod_negotiation will rewrite the URL from `item` to `item.php` (for example) before mod_rewrite and you won't get the URL parameters passed.

If you specifically need to check that the target file, eg. `page.php` exists before rewriting then you can include an additional condition to check this. However, I wouldn't have thought this was necessary since you'll get a 404 regardless and checking that the file exists is relatively expensive.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\w-]+)(?:/(\d+))?$ /$1.php?title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This assumes that your files exist in the document root of your site.

Just to clarify, as mentioned in comments, you should already be linking to URLs of the form `http://www.example.com/item/titlename/5` in your application.

Comment: That was a great effort, however it doesn't work for me.